# Issues using ListBuffer in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, listbuffer

```
package com.listbuffer.ex

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object IUEReclass{
   def main(args: Array[String]) {

     val codes = "XY|AB"
     val codeList = codes.split("|")
     var lb = new ListBuffer[String]()

     codeList.foreach(lb += "XYZ")

       val list = lb.toList

   }
```

I'm getting following exception.

```
[ERROR] C:\ram\scala_projects\Fidapp\src\main\scala\com\listbuffer\ex\ListBufferEx.
scala:38: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
[INFO]  required: String => ?
[INFO]
                lb += "XYZ"
[INFO]`enter code here`
                          ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `codeList` is `Array[String]`, which is because [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method on `String`s will return an `Array[String]`.

Now you have a `Array[String]` on which you are calling the [`foreach`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer) method, so what you should pass to this function is a function from a `String` to `Unit`. What you are giving it instead is a `ListBuffer[String]`, because [`+=`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer@-(elem:A):This) method on a `ListBuffer` will return a `ListBuffer`. This type inconsistency will cause the compile error.

### Details on `foreach` method

From the Scala docs of `foreach` method:

> Applies a function f to all elements of this array.

In this case elements of this array are of type `String` so the provided function to `foreach` should accept inputs of type `String`.

### Alternatives

If adding all elements of `codeList` to the `ListBuffer` is your intention, as mentioned by Paul in comments, you can do it with

```
codeList.foreach(code => lb += code)
```

or

```
codeList.foreach(lb += _)
```

Alternatively you can use the [`appendAll`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer@appendAll(xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):Unit) method from [`ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer@appendAll(xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):Unit):

```
lb.appendAll(codeList)
```

which

> Appends the elements contained in a traversable object to this buffer.

according to the [Scala Docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer@appendAll(xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):Unit).

Comment: This is mostly right. But "What you are giving it instead is a function from ListBuffer[String]" is wrong - no function is being passed, but an expression. If the OP really wants to add XYZ for each element of codelList,. then `codeList.foreach { e => lb += "XYZ" }` will work (i..e a function of the correct type that ignores its argument). Probably the OP wants `{ e => lb += e}` though (or appendAll, which does the same)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.insertAll()`:

```
lb.insertAll(0, codeList)
val list = lb.toList
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP's code does, though (which adds "XYZ" codeList.length times). It's probably what the OP actually wants, though :) And `appendAll` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul, I'm able to fix it.

I just changed the code to have

codeList.foreach { e => lb += "XYZ" }

Thanks much everyone who took time to look at the issue!!

Regards

Ram